# Multi-Tenant and EF6 Design

Tags: entity-framework, multi-tenant

I'm designing a multi tenant website using EF6 code first, MVC, and other from the MS stack.

I want to have announcements for each Tenant.  Simple enough, my EF code first class would look something like this:

```
class Announcement
{
    public Announcement()
    {
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
}
```

My design question is what if I want the site administrator to have the ability to post announcements to all tenants?

Since the database will force the Tenant relationship, I can't set the Tenant property to something artificial.

Before EF, I'd do something like this, but now I will lose the nice-to-have EF Navigation property.

```
class Announcement
{
    public Announcement()
    {
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public int TenantID { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
}
```

I would use TenantID appropriately for all Tenant based announcements, but would set it to 0 for site wide announcements.

So, is there a better design (other than two classes/tables) that can still leverage the EF Navigation properties?

Comment: Why did you opt for the model with out a tenantid. You could have set it as a nullable property in db and model will be having `public int? tenantId {get;set;} `

Comment: That is the basis of my question.  I know I can use an int TenantID field (nullable or not), but then I lose the nice-to-have EF Navigation property.

Comment: I think in a multi-tenant application you should have separate structures for tenant-independent stuff. In this case: a separate `SiteAnnouncement` table. It may look redundant, but you really should regard tenant data as separate databases. What if, for instance, in the future you want to record which tenant has read which announcement? That would be quite different for both types of announcements.

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue with

```
class Announcement
{
    public Announcement()
    {
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    }

[Key]
public virtual int Id { get; set; }

public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

public virtual string Title { get; set; }

public virtual  string Message { get; set; }

public virtual  int TenantID { get; set; }  // during insert/Update set as required. the tenant should exist. 
                                            // A dummy SYSTEM wide tenant may be an option to consider

// navigation props
[ForeignKey("TenantID")]
public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; } // <<<<< NAV as before

public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How would you enter a system wide announcement?  With your class, I think only the dummy tenant would work.

Comment: The system wide  entries would apply to all Tenants. Off course if you need tenant level message control. ie Tenant X has read/received the message, so it is no longer displayed etc, then actually write a record per tenant may be required.  But your designing this not me.  I was just pointing out there is away having the NAV. and also that the class with NAV wasnt  quite declared as expected.